# How to make user input with voice gtts

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, google-text-to-speech

I am creating a simple pizza app with voice inputs. 
Before creating this post i have searched a lot and didn't find anything useful.

[This is the full code](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/bd884a16-cf14-4af7-89ae-3cfd6853c344/?i=true)

The fiddle doesn't run the code appropriately so don't run it over there.

**The issue:**

When i try to use **"command"** in my **"input"** (**e.g.**

```
count = 0

def talkToMe(audio):

    global count
    print(audio)
    text_to_speech = gTTS(text=audio, lang='en-us')
    text_to_speech.save(f'speech{count%2}.mp3')
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load(f'speech{count%2}.mp3')
    mixer.music.play()
    count += 1

def myCommand():


    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('Ready...')
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        command = r.recognize_google(audio).lower()
        print('You said: ' + command + '\n')

    #loop back to continue to listen for commands if unrecognizable speech is received
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print('Your last command couldn\'t be heard')
        command = myCommand();

    return command

def assistant(command):

    def pick_or_deli():
        global delivery
        global customer_name 
        global customer_telephone

        delivery = input("pickup - pick up / delivery - delivery:" + command)
        delivery = delivery.upper()
        if delivery == "DELIVERY":
             while running == True:
        ..............................
```

i am simply getting:

[image: this]

Don't pay attentio on lowercase "delivery". 
Even if i change this line:

```
if delivery == "DELIVERY":
```

to this:

```
if delivery == "delivery":
```

It doesn't work. Even if i hit enter. The system doesn't recognize it as an input.

Any solutions/suggestions on this would be great.

Comment: Some things do not quite fit here. In your code the prompted message is different from the output in the image. Have you tried debugging your script by simply printing the value of `delivery` before `if delivery == 'DELIVERY': ...`?

Comment: @Sven Krüger Thank you for reply. Seems like print didn't show anything. I have changed this line `if delivery == "delivery":` to `if command in delivery:` and indicated delivery as: `delivery = ['delivery']`. So now it recognizes it and skips this part succesfully but it adds also my voice input for delivery to the name input: as: `Pickup or delivery? ready... You said: delivery     Name:delivery` again even if i hit enter it doesn't recognize it as an input: `Name:delivery Please enter a valid input    Name:delivery`

Comment: What are you actually aiming at by writing `delivery = input("pickup..." + command)`? Do you want to pass the value of `command` to the function `input`? Because the addition of two strings is simply a concatenation. So if you only hit enter at the console the return value of `input` will be an empty string.